# How to perform jQuery-style serial animations in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and want to animate a button on hover, like I could do using jQuery. First I want to change the height. When that animation is done (which I would check for using `.stop()` in jQuery), I want to then animate the weight. What is the best way to do this in React?

Answer (score 0):

A good solution for simple usecases is to include [react-transition-group](http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/).

Examples here: http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/css-transition

Comment: How would you do one animation after another with react-transition-group.

Comment: You can nest `Transition` and also `TransitionGroup` if you need it.
In brief: you put a Transition, when it completed you render children which contains another Transition (or CSSTransition)

Comment: Can you show an example? I'm missing the .stop() knows from jQuery.